# Use method to draw an image

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

I am currently learning JavaScript [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Here I created a constructor called person. And I gave it a prototype property to draw each new person's face (I mean an image) on the canvas. I have introduced different alert commands to check if it is working or not. I think I did everything right, but for some reason the image is not being drawn on the canvas.

**JavaScript**

```
function draw(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
    var person = function (name, age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    };

    person.prototype.drawit = function(src, xpos, ypos, width, height) {
        this.src = src;
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = this.src;
        ctx.drawImage(img, this.xpos, this.ypos, this.width, this.height);
    };

    var person1 = new person("winsteen", "14");
    person1.drawit("lol1", 200, 200, 40, 50);
    alert(person1.age);
    alert(person1.src);
}

window.onload = draw;
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Check your console, any errors?

Comment: it isn't giving any error..

Comment: Are you sure `"lol1"` is the correct relative path to your image? It does not seem to include a file extension (e.g. jpg, png, gif)

Comment: haven't thought about it for a single moment.no error report for this one either.adding a .jpg extension drew the image prefectly :)).

Answer (score 2):

This is because your image takes time to load, and you draw the image before it is loaded. After setting the `img.src`, set an `img.onload` to a function doing the drawing. This function will get called asynchronously as soon as the image is loaded and is ready to be drawn.

If you want to use the `this` keyword you need to bind your load handler, because, like Paul said, it would otherwise refer to the image.

```
img.onload = drawIt.bind(this);
function drawIt(){
   // Your drawing method, doing nothing but drawing the image to the canvas.
}
```

I noticed a bunch of other things in your code you could change. At the moment a lot of your code is redundant, you don't need to pass the xpos, ypos, width, height, etc. in your `drawIt` method. It should be set / stored in your object constructor, so your drawIt method is called without arguments and will draw it based on the values stored in your object.

If you want a way to set these values, make another method to set them.

The same goes for setting/loading the image. You don't want to create a new image and load it every time you draw it. Make a separate "loadImage" method that loads the image and calls drawIt once the image is loaded (as shown in my above example).

When to use `bind()`:

You want to use the `this` keyword to access the instance variables and create functions that work the same on many different objects, because 'this.width' refers to a `Person.width` or a `Street.width` or basically any width, depending on the context of the function. The method stays the same and `this` will change.

But if you use an event listener `this` may not always behave like you expect it. `bind()` is a method you can use on any function, and it permanently replaces this function with a new one that will *always* execute in the context you provide as the first argument for `bind()`.

In other words: You create a new copy of the function where `this` is permanently set to a specific object. In this case it will be your Person.

Comment: i used   img.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,this.xpos,this.ypos,this.width,this.height);
    }      is it ok? it isn't working either

Comment: 1. set the _onload_ before the _src_, 2. inside the _load_ handler, `this` refers to the `<img>`, 3. make sure you can actually see what you're trying to draw; i.e. white on white = invisible

Comment: ok did something like this   img.onload=function(){
  img.src=this.src;
  ctx.drawImage(img,this.xpos,this.ypos,this.width,this.height);
    }   still no image.it is a yellow smiley face.so no chance to become invisible here

Comment: what does bind() do specifically?i have encountered it for the first time here...

Comment: @user3138436 `bind` creates a copy of a function. The value of `this` inside the copy has the value of the first parameter of `bind`, irrelevant of how it's invoked

Answer (score 1):

1. The image must load before it can be drawn.
2. Inside a handler on an `<img>`, `this` will be that `<img>`.
3. Check using high contrast when debugging, so you don't get e.g. white on white.

A little refactoring, and you'll end up with something like this:

```
(function () { // Immediately-invoked_function_expression (IIFE) keeps
               // global namespace clean - see
               // <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression>.
    function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
                     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 600;
        canvas.height = 600;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

        function Person(name, age) { // Constructors usually start with a capital letter
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        Person.prototype = {
            constructor: Person // Good to let instances know who they are
        };

        Person.prototype.drawit = function (src, dx, dy, dw, dh) {
            var img;
            this.src = src;
            // Etc. if you want to store these
            img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // `this` here means `img`, access the other values directly
                // from their variables.
                ctx.drawImage(this, dx, dy, dw, dh);
            });
            img.src = src; // Initiate image load
        };

        // Finished setup, now use
        var person1 = new Person("Winsteen", "14");
        person1.drawit("lol1", 200, 200, 40, 50);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', draw); // Safe wait for page load
}()); // Invoke the IIFE
```

Comment: I don't think giving him a copy-pastable solution that's full of intermediate javascript concepts like registering event handlers, animmediately executing anonymous function keeping global namespace clean he won't be able to understand really helps him at this point when he just starts out.

Comment: i appreciate it.pointed out lots of new key-words  to learn from here  :).thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: @Winchestro I doubt that OP just wants one "person" loaded in, and if they just copy/pasted this without attempting to understand what is going on it is unlikely that they'd be able to change it to do all they want of it. I've included comments to help point them in the right direction as they read through it. As OP said they're learning OOP in _JavaScript_ and not that they're new to the whole language, I expect that the other concepts (IIFE, event handlers) will require little new learning to reach. That said, I understand how a simple copy/paste doesn't help you learn :(

Comment: Fair enough :) I try to balance examples vs explanation based on how much potential/interest I see in a particular question. If someone clearly just needs a quick solution (because js isn't the main interest) I'll post some working code, otherwise I try to explain as much as possible and leave as much as possible to figure out / write for themselves. But I'm always curious how other people see it, who are longer on this website than me, because I want to improve my ability to teach / communicate concepts :)

Comment: @Winchestro It's good to explain a lot and leave them to do a lot, but I've found that if the answer doesn't include any examples of some code, they can give up and stop being interested, it can be a difficult balance to perfect

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) I'll think about that. Maybe adding more example code that illustrates a certain idea, but doesn't give away the solution right away (I experimented with this a bit but some people complained because it's not "the solution to the problem")^^